# On which site to post shell/bash/zsh questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been using StackExchange sites frequently for several months now.  However, I'm still baffled as to where to post shell/bash/zsh questions.  SuperUser, ServerFault, Unix and Linux, StackOverflow, and AskUbuntu all seem like good candidates.

For example, I want to ask a question about how to see zsh default settings for variables like HISTSIZE and SAVEHIST.  On which site do you recommend asking this question?

Comment: You left out [unix.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), as most bash related questions are not ubuntu specific...

Comment: I wouldn't go anywhere else but unix.se for my shell/bash/etc questions. There's a few bods over there who really *really* know their stuff.

Comment: Thanks dmckee and @Kev, that's helpful!  I've now added "Unix and Linux" to the list above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, search.

- SO has a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag; predictably it's often used for scripting
- Super User has a [bash tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash) too. Note they're less about scripting and more about using it as a normal user; just getting around, what commands there are
- AskUbuntu basically has both types of questions in it's [bash tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash)

Bash is on topic on all three sites; if you're using it as a programmer to do programmy things, ask on SO. If you're using it as a normal user, Super User is appropriate. Since it's a Linux tool, Unix and Linux is appropriate, as is AskUbuntu. It all depends where you need your answers from; would you ask a programmer, a Linux geek, or a device agnostic group of enthusiast geeks?

Comment: To clarify what Ben is saying, this is one of those special topics where you can actually take into account the audience whom you wish to direct your questions to...

Comment: @jmort253 really you should *always* take into account the audience to whom you wish to direct your question to...sites are based as much/more around communities than topics

Comment: I agree with your statement, but my point was that in most cases I can't really ask the English Language and Usage folks what they think about my programming problem just because I want to know what they think. I know that's an "out-there" example, but that's sort of what I was getting at. In the op's example, there is more than one applicable choice. Many times there is just one choice and that's it.